# Which Android Smartphones or Tabs are enabled with Wireless Adhoc Network?

Tags: ad-hoc-networks

I am planning to create an AdHoc Network with 3 Android Smartphones. But I am confused about the products. Is Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 enabled with AdHoc Network? I don't understand which Android smartphones/Tabs can be useful for building this type of AdHoc Network.... Please Help

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked with our [ad-hoc-networks tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ad-hoc-networks/info)? This most likely answers your question. If not, please [edit] it and include what you've checked, and what issues remained open.